# How to target an element nestled in several unidentified tables?

Tags: css

*I have no access to editing the HTML, I can only updated the CSS to change the styling.*

I want to change an input field to be 100% width, but the field has the same class as another field where I want the width to be 50% (so basically, if I edit this field in the CSS directly, it will change both, which I don't want).

The field I want to change is nestled in several un-classed tables, but the parent table does have a class. Is there a way to target this specific input field?

```
<table class="findrepComponent">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="zip">
```

Comment: Sure. But where is the field that needs to be 50% width?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

not sure what's the constriction

```
.findrepComponent input{
        width:50%;
    }
```

this means input in findrepComponent class

or more specific

```
.findrepComponent table talbe input{
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#zip[type="text"] {

 <some stylesheets>

}
```

Comment: Is `[type="text"]` necessary? You're already selecting with and ID.

Comment: IDs aren't classes and shouldn't be re-used. If there is another `#zip` it could easily be `type="text"`.

Comment: @hungerstar let's say the author has a few pages using a single css. One `#zip` is `input`, on the other page `#zip` is a `div`, for example.

Comment: I fully understand that. If the other _"field"_ is `<input id="zip" type="text">` this fails. For this solution to work you need a specific set of conditions to be met, of which, we cannot be sure of and IMHO should be addressed in your answer. OP needs to provide additional specifics.

Comment: @hungerstar however in question, the author speaks of class.

Comment: That doesn't solidify anything, only raises more questions and uncertainty.

Comment: @hungerstar and why are you telling me this? get to the author. )))

Comment: See previous comments, :P. Someone already asked for clarification.